# Lost Data on Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, data

After I could not boot my Macbook Pro (OS X Lion 10.7.5) I tried to run safe boot. I thought it worked, but only thing it did was booting the mac without any data i used to have. All the software is there. It's like a brand new mac with full applications. My storage seems as full as before so I know the data is somewhere inside my Macbook. How can I find them? (I'm still logged in as I always were and there seems to be no other accounts)

P.S: I know the ways that requires payment, but I (with my ignorant logic) conclude that since my storage is still seems full with everything I have I may not need it.

Edit: ALSO i downloaded data rescue demo to scan. But for some reason my HD can't be scanned. When I tried Disk Warrior it says "Directory cannot be rebuild because this is the startup disk"

Comment: Did you have a look at your Trash? Did you try to use Spotlight to search for some file names/content you remember?

Comment: Yes I did. Trash is empty and spotlight doesn't come up with anything @patrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search your computer with [Grand Prespective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net) and it will show you your entire mac, and what and where the data is

Comment: no problem glad i could be of assistance